# Jquery & secton is not hiding my logo div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide my logo only on one div and show it on another. In one of my sections, I have a video so I do not need to show my logo. I cant however do it at all. It either just hides forever or just does not want to hide at all.

I have tried both style="" inside the div and jquery. None of which works.

My HTML structure:

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<header id="header" class="header-left">        
    <div class="header-inner clearfix">

        <!-- LOGO -->
        <div id="logo" class="logo-left">
            <a href="index.html">
                     <img id="dark-logo" src="files/uploads/logo_dark.png" srcset="files/uploads/logo_dark.png 1x, files/uploads/logo_dark@2x.png 2x" alt="Logo Dark">
                     <img id="light-logo" src="files/uploads/logo_light.png" srcset="files/uploads/logo_light@2x.png 1x, files/uploads/logo_light@2x.png 2x" alt="Logo Light">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
        <div id="menu" class="clearfix">            

            <div class="menu-actions">
                <div class="menu-toggle"><span class="hamburger"></span></div>
            </div> <!-- END .menu-actions -->

            <div id="menu-inner">
                <nav id="main-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">xxx</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">xxx</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="xxx.html">xxx</a></li>
                        <li><a href="xxx.html">xxxx</a></li>
                        <li><a href="xxx.html">xxx</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <span class="pseudo-close header-close"></span>
</header>
```

Ok so before I show the source, here is **what works**:

```
 <style>#logo img{opacity:0;visibility:hidden;}</style>
```

Pretty standard right? So I tried hiding the logo in this same way into a section and **it did not work**. Example:

```
<section id="page-body" class="fullwidth-section text-dark" style="#logo img{opacity:0;visibility:hidden;}">

....

</section>
```

I then tried jQuery to hide the logo as a test. **This did not work** at all. Example:

```
<script src="files/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


$("#logo").css({
display: "none",
visibility: "hidden"
});

$("#logo").hide();

</script>
```

What I was hoping to do is hide the logo in a single div then show it for the rest of the page. I had an idea to do this with jQuery or a section. Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: just try `$("#logo").hide()` if hide only img `$("#logo").find('img').hide()`

Comment: Hey, tried this but it did not work. The logo is still shown on the page?

Answer (score 1):

```
style="#logo img{opacity:0;visibility:hidden;}"
```

This is not a valid HTML `style` attribute. It's a selector for CSS that should be nested under the HTML's `<style>` tag.

When setting an element's `style` attribute, you only need to write the style properties. This is how it should look:

```
style="opacity:0;visibility:hidden;"
```

Your jQuery attempt to hide the logo should work when you remove the `logo` element's `style` tag. Doing `$('#logo').hide();` should work and is enough.

**A few notes:**

1. Using `opacity:0;` with `visibility:hidden;` doesn't make sense. Use either one of them, both make the element invisible.
2. You can just write `$('#logo').hide();`, no need to the whole `$("#logo").css({` section.
3. You can shorthand `$(document).ready(function(){` to just `$(function() {`
4. Keep in mind using `visibility:hidden;` keeps the element inline the page, but invisible. If you want to make it disappear completely, use `display:none;`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Much appreciated however my problem still stands. The hide function does not remove it via jquery. Why is that? I have it in my header but also tried to put it at the bottom as well. Neither of which works?

Comment: How does your `logo` element look like? Paste the element here.

Comment: Also - are you sure you included Jquery script link to your HTML page?

Comment: Yes I have added <script src="files/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> above all!

Comment: Is the website live? Can I see it somehow?

Comment: No its local + private but the code is all there, I just dont know why it wont hide? It makes no sense..

Answer (score 0):

You can't write inline style to another element.Inline styles are applicable to the element itself.

This is the right way

```
<style>#logo img{opacity:0;visibility:hidden;}</style>
```

This is not possible

```
<section id="page-body" class="fullwidth-section text-dark" style="#logo img{opacity:0;visibility:hidden;}">

....

</section>
```

Try

```
section #logo img{opacity:0;visibility:hidden;}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but how do I only apply the logo hide for one section?